# Apache - how to map prefixes to different directories

Tags: apache, configuration, virtualhost

Is it possible to configure Apache to allow different prefixes (instead of www) to map to different directories in the file system? For example...

I have two different environments on my webserver:

```
  /home/me/test/web : Test Environment
  /home/production/web : Production Environment
```

I would like these to map to these urls:

```
  test.mysite.com -> /home/me/test/web
  prod.mysite.com -> /home/production/web
```

However, nothing I've tried with VirtualHosts has worked:

```
  NameVirtualHost *:80

  <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName test.mysite.com
      ** Some SetEnvs **
  </VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName prod.mysite.com
      ** Different SetEnvs **
  </VirtualHost>
```

This throws the following error:

```
  [warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence
```

Is this kind of configuration even possible with Apache, or am I doing something wrong? Also, some clarification - simple rewriting with a virtualhosts file probably won't fit either. It works for straight directory stuff, but then I can't use any SetEnv directives like I could within a VirtualHost section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be `:` not `.`:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Comment: Thanks, mistyped it when copying it over. It is correct in the .conf file, however.

Comment: @grobolom In this case you have some directives declared twice: double check that you have 1) `NameVirtualHost *:80` declared only once and 2) Please check all `<VirtualHost>` declarations -- you may have the same `ServerName` declared twice.

Comment: @grobolom Also try executing on of this commands (depends what distro you have) `apache2 -S` or `httpd -S` and check the output -- it may give you a location of duplicated `<VirtualHost>` **IF** it is the case for your warn message.

Comment: Well... yes, I know I have two similar sections. My warning message occurs because apache doesn't accept test.mysite.com and prod.mysite.com as virtual hosts on the same IP. I am wondering if there is a way to get around this, since something like [test.mysite.com/prod.mysite. **org** ] does work on a single box.

Comment: I have over 10 domains declared in similar way on my dev box. The snipped you have in your question is **fine**. Has to be something else - which you not showing. And what do you mean by _"I have two similar sections"_?

Comment: I meant that my sections are virtually identical except for the different servername. I've run the httpd -S command, and it returned the following:

`*:80 test.mysite.com *:80 prod.mysite.com *:* www.myothersite.com _default_:433 www.anothersite.com Segmentation fault`

I've double-checked my conf files and I don't have any duplicated ServerNames. : (

Comment: @grobolom Well, in this case I recommend asking this question in more appropriate place: http://serverfault.com/ (a sister site of Stack Overflow). Alternatively -- try resetting your Apache config to original one and start from scratch adding one domain at a time (should not take long).