# Adding VirtualHost breaks all other server folders

Tags: apache, hosting, virtualhost

I am trying to run designer-school.com on my server. I have added this VirtualHost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/backendtwo
ServerName www.designer-school.com
<Directory /var/www/html/backendtwo>
Allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This now means I can access the domain designer-school.com
But if i try and access other folders on this server I get 404 errors for example 
http://joshhornby.co.uk/typewriter

And also If i try and access a blog post on the root website
http://joshhornby.co.uk/post/web-course

Is there a way to run the domain designer-school on the server but it won't impact the other sites running on the server?

I have looked at running multiple VirtualHosts must when I restart the server I get this message

```
[warn] _default_ VirtualHost overlap on port 80, the first has precedence
```

Is there something in my .haccess file I need to change?

Comment: Because you are using `*:80` it is a(nother) default virtual host. Give it a different “name” instead of `*`.

Comment: I have just tried this now, giving the name typerwriter:80 still has no effect and I get a 404. Also nothing here about changing the 'name' http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: May I suspect you might be lacking the `NameVirtualHost` clause?

Comment: Yes thank you I have now added it also with Listen 80. But this now mean for each new blogpost I will have to add a VirtualHost which seems like a massive overkill.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache - how to map prefixes to different directories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942980/apache-how-to-map-prefixes-to-different-directories)